# Getting error on installing bootstrap subtheme?

Tags: 8

Why i am getting this error **"Unable to install bootstrap_subtheme, THEMENAME.settings has unmet dependencies"**. ?

Also my themename.theme file showing error on renaming **"The item could not be renamed."** for removing this error i created a clone blank file with name bootstrap_subtheme.theme and copy content of original themename.theme file ,paste it into the bootstrap_subtheme.theme file and finally deleted the original themename.theme file.

Still i am getting the following error **Unable to install bootstrap_subtheme, THEMENAME.settings has unmet dependencies**.

Comment: `THEMENAME` is a placeholder and should be replaced in all filenames and inside of the files.

Comment: i already did in all the files

Comment: Then the error message wouldn't know about THEMENAME. Did you replace the placeholder in subfolders too?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error message and here's how I fixed it.  In your subtheme folder (docroot/themes/bootstrap_subtheme) there's a config folder with two subfolders: install and schema.  Each of these subfolders has a YML file with THEMENAME in the file name, I just changed THEMENAME to my subtheme name and then I was able to install my subtheme.